# Recuperar un registro con el caracter º de mysql con php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Al recuperar de datos con php desde una BBDD y colocarlos en un objeto para devolverlo al ajax.

El problema está en que si los registros en la base de datos contienen el símbolo `º` los datos no son devueltos en forma correcta.

El campo en la base de datos esta definido como varchar con `utf8mb4_general_ci`.

¿Existe alguna forma de solucionar esto?

```
case "getDatosConservacion":

                    /*Procesamiento de consulta para las condiciones de conservacion*/
                    $ConservacionDB = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM estado_conservacion");
                    /*Procesamiento de consulta para los sectores*/
                       $cr = 0;
                       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ConservacionDB))
                        {
                          $conservacion[$cr]['id']    = $row['id'];
                          $conservacion[$cr]['codigo_conservacion']  = $row['codigo_conservacion'];
                          $conservacion[$cr]['conservacion'] = $row['conservacion'];
                          $cr++;
                      }
                         $jsonConservacion = json_encode($conservacion);
                         echo $jsonConservacion;
                         break;
```

Si alguno de los campos de la base de datos tiene un simbolo º la informacion devuelta vacia y de tipo string. La petición Ajax termina bien porque me da estado 200 pero no me devuelve un objeto. 
Si saco los símbolos º de los registros de la base de datos desde el admin de mysql el codigo funciona bien.

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con "los datos no son devueltos en forma correcta"?

Comment: muéstranos lo que tienes. para que te puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en el metodo json_encode que seguramente esta devolviendo false por el caracter especial, es un problema con la codificacion que tiene que ser UTF-8, puedes probar con `json_encode($conservacion, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);` puedes ver el error imprimiendo el metodo

```
$jsonConservacion = json_encode($conservacion);
echo json_last_error_msg();//Ver error
```

Con eso podras verificar el error que pueden ser segun la documentacion de php.net:

```
> JSON_ERROR_NONE   No ocurrió ningún error   
JSON_ERROR_DEPTH    Se ha
> excedido la profundidad máxima de la pila  
> JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH JSON con formato incorrecto o inválido   
> JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR  Error del carácter de control, posiblemente se ha
> codificado de forma incorrecta      
JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX   Error de sintaxis    
> JSON_ERROR_UTF8   Caracteres UTF-8 mal formados, posiblemente
> codificados de forma incorrecta   PHP 5.3.3 
JSON_ERROR_RECURSION    Una o
> más referencias recursivas en el valor a codificar    PHP 5.5.0
> JSON_ERROR_INF_OR_NAN Uno o más valores NAN o INF en el valor a
> codificar PHP 5.5.0 
JSON_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_TYPE
```

Comment: Muchas gracias... voy  a probarlo